# Adding YAML syntax highlighting throughout an entire markdown file (in vim)

Tags: vim, syntax

I currently have the plugin [vim-markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown) installed. Among other things, it adds syntax highlighting to markdown files. But frequently in markdown files there are yaml headers:

```
---
yaml: contents
more: yaml
---

# Usual markdown
Etc.
```

Using vim-markdown, the part of this file enclosed in `---` is correctly rendered as yaml (from a syntax highlighting point of a view). The rest of the file is rendered as markdown.

**Question:** How do I make it so that, no matter where the enclosing `---` are located -- yaml is rendered in between?

**Attempt:** I found in the `~/.vim/bundle/vim-markdown/syntax/markdown.vim` the following snippet:

```
syn include @yamlTop syntax/yaml.vim
syn region Comment matchgroup=mkdDelimiter start="\%^---$" end="^---$" contains=@yamlTop
```

I removed the `\%` in the `start=` field and tried again. But it didn't work :(

Comment: I suspect it would conflict with [the setext header](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.22/#setext-headers) syntax definition. What if you have blank lines before the opening `---`, and `\%` removed from the `start` pattern above?

Answer (score 1):

In case you have not yet found the solution: Add the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:vim_markdown_frontmatter = 1
```

It is documented here:

https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown